# Did not receive Enlightened badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I was skimming through my badges and noticed that I have an accepted answer (for [How to maintain a sometimes-used vehicle](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/12/5)) with 10+ up votes yet I do not have the Enlightened badge.

Looking at the text describing the badge it says

> First answer was accepted with at
>   least 10 up votes

To earn the badge, does the answer have to have 10+ up votes BEFORE being selected as the accepted answer?

OR

Should the badge be awarded whenever an accepted answer reaches 10 up votes?

Answer (score 5):

In order to earn the Enlightened badge, your answer needs to be the first answer on the question.  It does not matter when the answer is accepted in relation to receiving upvotes.

In the question you linked to, your answer was not the first answer posted.